# Unable to change z order for animated view

Tags: android, animation, view, z-order

I have tried to solve this problem for several hours now, but I totally no idea what to do.

I have a `LinearLayout` with two `RelativeLayout`s, each the same height. The bottom ones visibility is "gone" before the animation starts and I want it to "slide out" of the top one `onClick`. The slide works perfectly, but the animated view is ALWAYS on top of the other one, no matter what I do. As it should look like the bottom one is "sliding out", that is not the effect I want to achieve.

My animation looks like this:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    />
```

I have already tried to do `view.bringToFront()` with the view that is not animated and should just stay on top of the animated one. But as a result the not animated view is displayed as the bottom view.

Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported in layout's like Relative layout and framelayout where z-index placement of children views are supported. You can try:

```
view.bringToFront();
```

Explanation from docs: **Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling views.**

You can also try:

```
bringChildToFront(View child)
```

**Change the z order of the child so it's on top of all other children.**

These methods change the children views in the view tree. appropriate place to do it would be on animationEnded method of your animation.

Comment: Thanks man! Changing the wrapping ContainerLayout of both RelativeLayouts also to a RelativeLayout was the key. Works fine now!